# Issues with nmap scan using ssh socks proxy with proxychains

Tags: ssh, proxy, tcp, nmap, proxychains

I have a socks proxy made available to a remote computer, using ssh:

```
ssh -D 127.0.0.1:9999 remoteuser@remotemachine
```

I've adjusted the `/etc/proxychains.conf`:

```
quiet_mode 
socks4 127.0.0.1 9999
```

After a couple of tests, I've learned that `proxychains` can't handle `nmap`'s SYN scans and neither does it support UDP or ICMP, so I've restricted my `nmap` scan:

```
proxychains nmap -sT X.X.X.X --top-ports 1000 -vv
```

This appears to be working fine, although slow, when looking at the terminal running `nmap`, but the terminal displaying the `ssh` socks proxy, goes wild with the following message:

```
channel 2: open failed: connect failed: Connect failed
```

I'm assuming that this is feedback of the TCP connect scan. Does this impact the result of the scan or is this a common message? Is there a way to suppress non-critical messages?